# Where do all the Super Villains come from?

Tags: jupiters-legacy

In Jupiter's Legacy, we get two story lines moving forwards. The life and times of heroes battling super villains in 2019 and the "how we got our powers" plot thread set in 1929.

In 2019, the Union appears to be entirely made up of the remainder of the original 6 super heroes and their children. But there doesn't seem to be a homogenous back story for the super villains.

By the end of the 1929 plot thread we see the Heroes have their powers bestowed upon them from the outside after completing their "heroic journey", but where do the powered super villains come from?

Comment: [Jupiter’s Legacy is vague on the details and never confirms how exactly the new generation gained their powers — whether they were inherited or bestowed upon them in some other way is unclear for now.](https://screenrant.com/jupiters-legacy-characters-powers-not-union-how-island/)

Comment: `But there doesn't seem to be a homogeneous back story for the super villains.` Not yet...  I smell season 2 material on the wind.

Comment: @Paulie_D - In the comics the power is clearly inherited from genetic transfer or somesuch similar mechanism. You have multi-generational powered families.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comics, at least one of the villains is from outer space: [Blackstar](https://imagecomics.fandom.com/wiki/Blackstar_(Jupiter%27s_Legacy)). In the TV show, others such as [Raiku](https://imagecomics.fandom.com/wiki/Raikou_(Jupiter%27s_Legacy)) appear to be illegitimate children of Union members. Others may be descendants of the ship crew members who were 'irradiated' while they were anchored near the island (this is currently speculation).

Comment: I did see the flashes on the faces of the ship's crew. It looked like a decent potential hook.

Comment: Not to mention [denizens of parallel universes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TcvM.jpg).

Comment: And, of course you can make supervillains the old-fashioned way; https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO6R8.jpg